# Autosys dependencies on mainframe job

Tags: mainframe, autosys

we have the autosys job (job_a) that needs to be dependent on two mainframe jobs(job_m1,job_m2). and also there is one condition the new job should start after both mainframe job completes. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the vendor (CA) has a job management agent that can run on z/OS and report job status directly to Autosys. When you do this, your mainframe jobs become just like and other job on any other platform.

If this doesn't meet your needs, I'd definitely make it the vendor's problem - your company is paying them a considerable sum for ongoing support and maintenance, and answering this type of question should certainly be something they can do for you.